# How to update a param defined in the SDF file?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, sdf

I have a simulation with Gazebo-Garden and ros2-Humble to manage drones with a camera.
In the camera sensor SDF part I have:

```
<sensor name="camera" type="camera">
  <camera>
  [...]
  <always_on>1</always_on>
</sensor>
```

This makes all camera started at the begining.
I'd like to know if it is possible to set it to `false` in the SDF and then on user demand activate this camera.

I read to use service set_entity_state but it is not in my ros2 service list (and I wonder if it is a solution for gazebo-classic).

For info:

```
$ ros2 service list
/flotte/describe_parameters
/flotte/get_parameter_types
/flotte/get_parameters
/flotte/list_parameters
/flotte/set_parameters
/flotte/set_parameters_atomically
/ros_gz_bridge/describe_parameters
/ros_gz_bridge/get_parameter_types
/ros_gz_bridge/get_parameters
/ros_gz_bridge/list_parameters
/ros_gz_bridge/set_parameters
/ros_gz_bridge/set_parameters_atomically
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04